# How can I align columns where the biggest number or greatest string is the align indicator?

Tags: vim, alignment

How can I right align (and left align?) a block of numbers or text in vim like this:

from:

```
45    209   25     1
2      4     2     3
34      5   300     5
34    120   34    12
```

to this:

```
45    209    25    1
 2      4     2    3
34      5   300    5
34    120    34   12
```

That means the biggest number or greatest string in every column doesn't move.
In the first column it is 45+34, in the second column 209+120, in the third column 300 and in the last column 12.

Comment: Did you use spaces to get the input? When I use tabs to enter columns of numbers they are naturally left aligned.

Comment: @inTide, yes spaces (I don't use tabs in my buffers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Align and AlignMaps plugins:  select using V, then \anum (AlignMaps comes with Align).  One advantage of \anum is that it also handles decimal points (commas) and scientific notation.

Comment: Your plugin is great. It can do su much things but it is less easy to understand then Tabular. Another desadvantage I've found is that you cannot put the maps in the command line p.e. using them in menu.vim or vimrc. And .... the plugin uses a lot of maps starting with different letters. I wish they would be a bit more easy to remember (or to change by the user). I don't like the DrChip menu neither. (even worse.... I already tried the \anum before, the only thing what I didn't know that I had to select linewise.)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the `align` plugin, it can do this and much more. Great tool in your utility belt!

Found [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)

After some serious vimhelp/reading I found the correct `AlignCtrl` mapping...
Visually select the table, e.g. by using `ggVG`, then do a `\Tsp` i.e. `<leader>Tsp`

Then I get this:

```
 45   209    25    1
  2     4     2    3
 34     5   300    5
 34   120    34   12
```

From vimhelp:

```
\Tsp  : use Align to make a table separated by blanks |alignmap-Tsp|
        (right justified)
```

Comment: The 'align' plugin is nice, but the 'Tabularize' plugin (mentioned by yoda) is far superior.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into the [Tabularize](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) plugin. So if you have something like

```
45 209 25 1
2 4 2 3
34 5 300 5
34 120 34 12
```

just select those lines in the visual mode and type `:Tab/` and it will format it as

```
45   209   25    1
2    4     2     3
34   5     300   5
34   120   34    12
```

Also, it looks like you don't have an equal number of spaces separating the numbers at the moment. So before you use the plugin, replace all the multiple spaces with a single space with [the following regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860532/vim-regex-replace-multiple-consecutive-spaces-with-only-one-space/3860718#3860718):

```
%s![^ ]\zs  \+! !g
```

Comment: Please see my question. (btw...I have both the align and tabularize plugin but can't find out how to resolve my question).

Answer (score 3):

With the [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) you can select the rows you want to align and hit :

`<Leader>Tsp`

From Align.txt

```
  \Tsp  : use Align to make a table separated by blanks |alignmap-Tsp|
          (right justified)
```

(The help mention `\` because it is the default leader but in case you have changed it to something else you must adapt accordingly)

Just trying on my install, I got the following result :

```
45   209    25    1
 2     4     2    3
34     5   300    5
34   120    34   12
```

In my opinion Align plugin is great but the "align maps" and various commands are not really easy to remember.

Comment: Yes I agree. DrChip (why does he call his self Dr.chip? ;)) creates good stuff but most things are difficult to find, to understand and not alway usable as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is to first eat all multiple spaces with

```
:{range}s/ \+/ /g
```

And then call Tabularize

```
:Tab / /r1
```

Or change that `r` to `l`.